# Trying to pip install a private repo in a DockerFile

Tags: python, git, docker, ssh, pip

I'm trying to install a custom Python package to run in a Flask Server. The server will be in a Docker image. Therefore, I'm trying to do a manipulation of the sort of `RUN pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:teamName/reponame.git@dev#egg=packageName`
However, nothing that I have tried works.

I've tried the two formats that I've found:

1) `git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:teamName/reponame.git@dev#egg=packageName`

2) `git+ssh://bitbucket.org/team/reponame.git@dev#egg=packageName`

Both of these technic give a similar error:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
```

or

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org:TeamName: Name does not resolve
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

or

```
root@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Even though my public key is set in BitBucket

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
 Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.6-alpine

#Preparation to pull from Github
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY

RUN echo "Oh dang look at that ${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}"

RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache openssh \
    git

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa


RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

#install dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc \
    bash \
    tzdata \
    g++ \
    tiff-dev \
    openssl \
    poppler \
    poppler-dev \
    poppler-utils \
    && pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org <THE_URL>
    && cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/that_place /etc/localtime \
    && echo "America/that_place" >  /etc/timezone \
    && date

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR ./my_dir

# Make port 5000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 5000

#Remove SSH
RUN rm /root/.ssh/id_rsa

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME __main__
ENV FLASK_APP app/app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ./resources/google/credentials.json
ENV GOOGLE_CLOUD_BUCKET_NAME bucket_name

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

The SSH key is passed as an Argument to the build with `$(cat ./ssh/id_rsa)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to pass in an SSH key that way: it will end up inside the resulting image, so anyone who has access to the image will have access to your SSH key.

Options:

1. Use BuildKit, which has built-in SSH agent forwarding (https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds).
2. Technique I describe here, too complex to cover in short scope of answer: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-build-secrets/
3. If you're not worried about leaking your private SSH key, fix this setup. My guess is you also need to `chmod 700 /root/.ssh`.

Comment: The SSH key is a deploy "read only" deploy ssh key. So not TOO dramatic but still, would rather not leak it. What do you mean by fix this setup?

Comment: To make the example you gave work, I suspect `chmod 700 /root/.ssh` will do the trick.